# generate elements based on key structure of object

Tags: javascript, recursion, dynamically-generated

I have an multidimensional object. Now I wanna generate DOM-elements based on the key structure of this object.

As a default view all root keys should be shown as div elements. With a click on one of this elements the divs should be replaced with the direct children of the clicked key.

My current version looks like this

object:

```
let object = {
    "1.0": {
        "1.0.1": {},
        "1.0.2": {},
    },
    "1.1": {
        "1.1.1": {
            "1.1.1.1": {},
        },
        "1.1.2": {},
    },   
};
```

this is my recursive function to generate DOM elements for each key:

```
function categoryTree(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        categoryContainer.innerHTML += "<div>" + key + "</div>";
        categoryTree(obj[key]);
    }
}
```

Now, I don't know how to make this interactive and show the child keys only when the parent was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build nested html structure with `createElement` and `for...in` loop. And then you can also add event listener on div that will toggle its children `display` property.

```js
let object = {
  "1.0": {
    "1.0.1": {},
    "1.0.2": {}
  },
  "1.1": {
    "1.1.1": {
      "1.1.1.1": {}
    },
    "1.1.2": {}
  }
}

let categoryContainer = document.querySelector(".categoryContainer")

function categoryTree(obj, parent, start = true) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = key;
    if (parent.children) parent.className += " bold";
    if (!start) div.className = "normal hide"

    div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation()
      Array.from(div.children).forEach(child => {
        child.classList.toggle('hide')
      })
    })
    categoryTree(obj[key], div, false)
    parent.appendChild(div)
  }
}


categoryTree(object, categoryContainer)
```

```css
.hide {display: none;}
.normal {font-weight: normal;}
.bold {font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<div class="categoryContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the DOM methods:

```
const n = (type, settings = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(type), settings);

function treeNode(name, children) {
  const text = n("p", { textContent: name });

  const container = n("div");
  container.style.display = "none";
  for(const [childName, child] of Object.entries(children))
    container.appendChild(treeNode(childName, child));

  const node = n("div");
  node.appendChild(text);
  node.appendChild(container);

  node.onclick = () => container.style.display = "block";

  return node;
}

categoryContainer.appendChild(treeNode("root", object));
```